# Angular Frontend / C# API Backend - Post FormData (file) and Object in same post

Tags: c#, angular, httpclient

Hoping someone can please help me understand the process to upload both a file (FormData) and Object from Angular to C# API.  From what I understand, the HttpClient Post method only accepts one body parameter, so I can post either the FormData object, or the 'SomeObject' object, but not both.  I have tried encapsulating 'SomeObject' in FormData (using FormData.append), without success.

Angular frontend code snippet:

```
uploadAttachment(abcId: number, someObject: SomeObject)
{
  const url = this.apiUrl + '/abc/' + abcId;

  const formData = new FormData();
  formData.append('file', fileData);

  return this.http.post<ScopeItemAttachment>(url, formData, 
  {
    reportProgress: true,
    observe: 'events'
  });
}
```

C# API snippet:

```
[HttpPost("{abcID}", Name = "UploadAttachment")]
public IActionResult UploadAttachment(int abcId, SomeObject someObject)
{
    try
    {
        var file = Request.Form.Files[0];
        var temp = Request.Form.Keys;

        if (file.Length > 0)
        {
            fileName = ContentDispositionHeaderValue.Parse(file.ContentDisposition).FileName.Trim('"');

            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            file.CopyTo(ms);

            ms.Close();
            ms.Dispose();

            return Ok();
        }
        else
            return BadRequest(new { message = "File content length must be greater than zero" });
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return StatusCode(500, $"Internal server error: {ex}");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that your `SomeObject` implementation is as below:

```cs
public class SomeObject
{
    public IFormFile File { get; set; }
}
```

1. Apply the `[FromForm]` attribute to the request body (`someObject`).
2. You can get the `file` via `someObject.File` rather than `Request.Form.File[0]`.

```cs
[HttpPost("{abcId}", Name = "UploadAttachment")]
public IActionResult UploadAttachment(int abcId, [FromForm] SomeObject someObject)
{

    var file = someObject.File;

    ...
}
```